# Calling an anonymous C function from Win32 binary

Tags: python, c, binary, ctypes

I am trying to access an anonymous function in a Win32 C Library binary from Python.
I found the function with Ghidra, and I have it's parameters and address and stuff.
With `ctypes` I did not find any info about how to add these manual functions, but only how to call "real", named functions.

I do not have the source code or any other stuff then the compiled library.

Is there a way to realize this?
Thanks for any help! :-)

Comment: You can’t call a function from an executable, after the code is compiled there is no ”functions” anymore. Just code and jumps.

Comment: I thought that ctypes would be able to recreate the functions based on the ``call`` instructions in the binary code.. Btw it's a shared library, I forgot the mention that.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a C file with a function that will call the anonymous function, the way you do it is to create a C pointer that is equal to the function location and than calling this C function through the pointer with the args you need from the python code.

Example:

```
In main.c:

typedef int (*func_pointer)(bool );

int func(bool arg) {
    # 0xdeadbeef - is the address of the function you wish to call
    func_pointer anon_function = (func_pointer)0xdeadbeef
    return anon_function(arg)
}
```

be sure to compile this as a DLL or an SO

more on calling c functions from python in this link:

https://www.journaldev.com/31907/calling-c-functions-from-python

Hope that helped

Comment: Thank you, sounds very nice! Is it enough to just link this code against the other library? My guess is that I would have to specify that the func ptr address I am providing is located in the other library..?

Comment: you would need to add the target library as well (the one with the anon function)